# drawing polygons with varying vertex count in OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es

so i'm a OpenGL newbie, but i reckon what i want to achieve is rather basic. I've got an amount of Cells coming from a 2D Voronoi diagram, i.e. connected convex polygons, and want to draw each of them as Triangle Fan.

glMultiDrawArrays would do exactly what i want because there you can specify the amount of vertices for each polygon. Unfortunately this function is not available on ES.

Comment: Not really an answer, but worth saying: glMultiDrawArrays isn't part of the ES spec, so sadly won't be available on any GL ES device — it's not just iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

- `glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES)`, with reuse of vertex indices in the index array.
- call `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN)` multiple times
- generate redundant vertexes, which also allows you to generate correct normals (probably not important for 2-D figures), and call `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES)`

Comment: i reckon the second option, multiple calls to glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN), would be the slowest? think i'm going with glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES) + redundant vertices for now. thanks!

Comment: Surely GL_TRIANGLES is going to require three indices to be fetched for all triangles, whereas GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP would require just two in the case where you're describing a fan? So TRIANGLE_STRIP with degenerates to link fans would be the better solution?

Comment: @Tommy: `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` can't draw a disconnected figure, which I think is what the question is desiring.

Comment: @Ben yes it can — you connect otherwise unrelated sections with degenerate (ie, zero surface area) polygons by duplicating indices. Because they're zero volume the GPU declines to draw anything. It's a standard option in model optimisers with a stripify function.

Comment: @Tommy: Until you choose to view a wireframe, in which case you see they actually are connected.  But I guess it will generate the desired output.  But couldn't you do that with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` as well?

Comment: @Ben: oh, yes, the slight fiction of hairline lines doesn't work, but I'm pretty sure glPolygonMode is missing from ES so for this one specific question the point is moot. Sure with triangle fan you've no way of ever escaping the very first point and setting a new anchor?

Comment: @Tommy: Emit the last point of the old fan twice and the first point of the new fan twice?  You end up with multiple degenerate triangles, but maybe fewer total vertices than with `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`.

Comment: @Tommy: Or maybe I'm confused about triangle fans vs strips.  Don't fans use the last two vertices plus one new one, and strips use the last one vertex plus two new ones?

Comment: @Ben I'm pretty sure TRIANGLE_FAN is the very first one + the most recent two, TRIANGLE_STRIP is the most recent three. So TRIANGLE_FAN can do convex polygons with an arbitrary number of edges just by passing them in, in order.

Comment: @Tommy: oh ok.  Now you know why I haven't been making any sense.

Comment: GL_TRIANGLES is not a problem - I'd wager that all current hardware has a vertex caches so recent vertices don't get re-processed. glDrawElements and GL_TRIANGLES is simple and will perform fine.

Comment: @ryanm: iPhone doesn't exactly have the most muscle in its GPU.  Reuse of indices might help with caching, but it really probably doesn't make much difference, since the application doesn't sound like its dealing with a huge number of polygons.